# How to get all paths of linked elements in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I have a set of elements and a set of directed links (sourceRef and targetRef). A directed acyclic graph.
How can I get all paths in the directed graph?

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element id="a" />
    <element id="b" />
    <element id="c" />
    <element id="d" />
    <element id="e" />

    <link sourceRef="a" targetRef="b" />
    <link sourceRef="b" targetRef="c" />

    <link sourceRef="a" targetRef="d" />
    <link sourceRef="d" targetRef="c" />

    <link sourceRef="a" targetRef="e" />

</root>
```

Desired Output:

```
    <paths>
        <path>
            <element id="a" />
            <element id="b" />
            <element id="c" />
        </path>
        <path>
            <element id="a" />
            <element id="d" />
            <element id="c" />
        </path>
        <path>
            <element id="a" />
            <element id="e" />
        </path>
    </paths>
```

[image: Problem as a graph]

XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 is preferred.

michael.hor257k answer produces the correct solution and even has a more elaborate example.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFuiXXU

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the nice tool.
I updated the data in there.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFuiXXU/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***--- edited in view of changed requirements ---***

If you search for *"enumerate paths in a directed graph"* you will find it is not at all a trivial problem. The following method will work for your (updated) example, but I am not certain it is a generic solution for all possible scenarios:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elem" match="element" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="prev-link" match="link" use="@targetRef" />
<xsl:key name="next-link" match="link" use="@sourceRef" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <paths>
        <!-- start with all origins -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="link[not(key('prev-link', @sourceRef))]"/>
    </paths>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:param name="vertices"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="key('next-link', @targetRef)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('next-link', @targetRef)">
                <xsl:with-param name="vertices" select="$vertices, key('elem', @sourceRef)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- reached a destination -->
            <path>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$vertices, key('elem', @sourceRef), key('elem', @targetRef)"/>
            </path>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Testing with a more challenging (?) case of:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <element id="a" />
    <element id="b" />
    <element id="c" />
    <element id="d" />
    <element id="e" />
    <element id="f" />
    <link sourceRef="a" targetRef="c" />
    <link sourceRef="b" targetRef="c" />
    <link sourceRef="c" targetRef="d" />
    <link sourceRef="d" targetRef="e" />
    <link sourceRef="d" targetRef="f" />
</root>
```

[image: digraph]

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paths>
   <path>
      <element id="a"/>
      <element id="c"/>
      <element id="d"/>
      <element id="e"/>
   </path>
   <path>
      <element id="a"/>
      <element id="c"/>
      <element id="d"/>
      <element id="f"/>
   </path>
   <path>
      <element id="b"/>
      <element id="c"/>
      <element id="d"/>
      <element id="e"/>
   </path>
   <path>
      <element id="b"/>
      <element id="c"/>
      <element id="d"/>
      <element id="f"/>
   </path>
</paths>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. For now it is good enough. It includes new concepts. I need some time to understand it.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to change the requirements after I posted my original answer. See if the updated version works for you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Sorry for changing the requirements, or not writing a good requirement in the first place. I knew it was not trivial, because I tried a lot. But I thought I was just missing some trivial part. Thanks for helping me with my first question.